# BeautifulSoup: How to get the document element from a tag?

Tags: beautifulsoup

It is easy to create a new tag using the Document object, but how do I create a new tag if I just have a tag?

```py
def bold(tag):
  b = tag.new_tag('b') # no new_tag method here
  tag.wrap(b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All elements have the `parents` generator, just get the last one:

```py
def bold(tag):
  b = list(tag.parents)[-1].new_tag('b') # find root element
  tag.wrap(b)
```

See @jason-s comment below for caveats.

Comment: This doesn't always work; it looks like it fails in cases where the tag has been extracted or perhaps otherwise modified.